# JSOUP - Help getting <IMG SRC> from <DIV CLASS>

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have the HTML snippet below. There are multiple div classes for "teaser-img" throughout the document. I want to be able to grab all the "img src" from all these "teaser-img" classes.

```
<div class="teaser-img">
    <a href="/julien/blog/failure-consciousness-vs-success-consciousness-shifting-focus-become-badass-or-loser">
        <img src="http://www.rsdnation.com/files/imagecache/blog_thumbnail/files/blog_thumbs/rsdnatonaustin.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have tried many things so I wouldn't know what code to share with you guys. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final String html = "<div class=\"teaser-img\">\n"
        + "    <a href=\"/julien/blog/failure-consciousness-vs-success-consciousness-shifting-focus-become-badass-or-loser\">\n"
        + "        <img src=\"http://www.rsdnation.com/files/imagecache/blog_thumbnail/files/blog_thumbs/rsdnatonaustin.jpg\" alt=\"\" title=\"\"/>\n"
        + "    </a>\n"
        + "</div>";

// Parse the html from string or eg. connect to a website using connect()
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);

for( Element element : doc.select("div.teaser-img img[src]") )
{
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

**Output:**

```
<img src="http://www.rsdnation.com/files/imagecache/blog_thumbnail/files/blog_thumbs/rsdnatonaustin.jpg" alt="" title="">
```

See [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for documentation about the selector syntax.